# OjbC Exception not caught in Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, exception, shazam, shazamkit

I've wrapped Swift code with a try-catch but it seems crashes from thrown exceptions still occur. Could it be that an objc exception is not caught by Swift?

```
do {
     try self.session.matchStreamingBuffer(buffer, at: time)
} catch {
   ...
}
```

and the crash looks like this:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e88 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  ShazamKit                      0x159d0 -[SHMutableSignature appendBuffer:atTime:error:]
3  ShazamKit                      0x6d7c -[SHSignatureGenerator appendBuffer:atTime:error:]
4  ShazamKit                      0x3968 -[SHSessionDriverSignatureSlot appendBuffer:atTime:error:]
5  ShazamKit                      0x10430 -[SHSignatureBuffer flow:time:]
6  ShazamKit                      0x2490 -[SHStreamingSessionDriver flow:time:]
7  ShazamKit                      0xf784 -[SHSession matchStreamingBuffer:atTime:]
8  Demo                           0x17ec24 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed AVAudioPCMBuffer, @guaranteed AVAudioTime) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
9  AVFAudio                       0x48f70 AVAudioNodeTap::TapMessage::RealtimeMessenger_Perform()
10 AVFAudio                       0x8044 CADeprecated::RealtimeMessenger::_PerformPendingMessages()
11 AVFAudio                       0x47ea8 invocation function for block in CADeprecated::RealtimeMessenger::RealtimeMessenger(applesauce::dispatch::v1::queue)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x746c _dispatch_continuation_pop
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1aa58 _dispatch_source_invoke
15 libdispatch.dylib              0xb56c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
16 libdispatch.dylib              0xc214 _dispatch_lane_invoke
17 libdispatch.dylib              0xd4f8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 _pthread_wqthread
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread
```

Comment: It seems odd though that I would have to go all this trouble for a modern Swift API.